# Change href value depending on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to rebuild the checkout process for my simple store and can't figure out how to change the `href=""` value depending on a selected option.

My code is:

```
<div class="nice-select" tabindex="0">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="scrollbar">
            <div class="list_item option focus" data-value="10">
                250 items <span class="price" data-count="250" data-price="10">$10</span></div>
            <div class="list_item option" data-value="25">
                500 items <span class="price" data-count="500" data-price="25">$25</span></div>
            <div class="list_item option" data-value="40">
            1000 items <span class="price" data-count="1000" data-price="40">$40</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<a href="" class="btn btn-info">Buy Now</a>
```

Just wanted to make something like if the option with the `data-value="10`" is selected, the href will be:

```
website.com/?add-to-cart=356&variation_id=15723
```

if the `data-value="25"` is selected the href will be `/?add-to-cart=356&variation_id=15725` etc

I'm not a JavaScript expert so would appreciate any help.

Comment: 1. Can the HTML change to an actual `select` element? 2. Or is this `nice-select` one of those things that has a `select` element hidden in the background it actually changes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I took some liberties in my solution because I couldn't replicate the functionality of your custom select elements.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bushwazi/pen/NWqEexQ)

Simplified HTML:

- not the same HTML, but you can use yours and it's related `change` event in place of what was done here.

```
<select>
  <option value="250"> 250 items -> $10</option>
  <option value="500"> 500 items -> $25</option>
  <option value="1000"> 1000 items -> $40</option>
</select>
<a href="htpps://website.com/?add-to-cart=356&variation_id=15723" class="btn btn-info">Buy Now</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// cache all the elements
var buyNowButton = document.querySelector("a");
var selectElement = document.querySelector("select");
var selectOptionElements = selectElement.querySelectorAll("option");
// create a map for the select to href value
var urlMap = {
  "250": 15723,
  "500": 15724,
  "1000": 15725
};

// listen to changes of the select
selectElement.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
  // replace the "search" value of the anchor href
  // use regex to find the current variation_id value and replace it using
  // selectedIndex and the urlMap and update it.
  buyNowButton.search = buyNowButton.search.replace(
    /variation\_id\=[0-9]+/,
    "variation_id=" +
      urlMap[selectOptionElements[selectElement.selectedIndex].value]
  );
});
```

[selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)
[anchor.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, href doesn't change :( I don't see any errors in the console or smthng.

Comment: In the codepen example I provided it does change, I can see it in devtools changing.

Answer (score 0):

Es simple, voy a darte tos alternativas:
En Javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('list_item');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('buynow').setAttribute('href', 'www.example.com?product=' + this.getAttribute('data-value'));
    });
}
```

En jQuery:

```
$('div.list_item option[data-value]').clicl(function(){
    $('a.btn').attr('href', 'www.example.com?product=' + $(this).data('data-value'));
});
```

Usa la que más te convenga según las librerías que usas.

Answer (score -1):

`document.querySelector("btn .btn-info").href="/?add-to-cart=356&variation_id=15725";` 
You can use onChange for `Select`, and depending by the value you can set the `href`

Comment: sorry, could you, please, let me know where exactly I need to change the code?